# Apache Rewrite Issue. Unable to figure out query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have been struggling on finding the rule to match this rewrite. I am working on a client website and it is a nightmare with the number of duplicate title tags. I have managed to resolve most of them by enforcing forward slash, redirect non www. to the www. version and disallow crawling of https version of the website.

The issue I am having at the moment. I have over 1000 URLs that are duplicate content, each product has two different URLs with the exact same content. An example is:

```
http://www.example.co.uk/product/widget1/
http://www.example.co.uk/widget1/
http://www.example.co.uk/product/widget2/
http://www.example.co.uk/widget2/
```

Now the following URLs have the same content:

```
http://www.example.co.uk/product/widget1/
http://www.example.co.uk/widget1/
```

I want to redirect any URL that contains "/product/" to the URL version without "/product/" in the URL if that makes sense. I honestly don't know where to start and would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The recommended rule:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/product/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]

does not work. It may be conflicting. These are the other rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/product/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

I dont know if there are any conflicts here. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your full .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.co.uk/$1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. How do I give you "Thanks" or "Rep" for your help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the URLs always *start* with product, this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/product/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]
```

It'll need to go in your main site conf or .htaccess

Comment: Have you tested this?